# How do i search an executable file and execute the same through batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I was trying to search an executable file & run the same file.
i have tried many things but its not done.
in searching i have used "dir /b /s xyz.exe" but no option to execute it in same batch.
please help me on this to get it done.

Comment: If by "same batch file" you're ruling out creating another temporary batch file, then you're correct. Otherwise, you could do: `dir /b /s xyz.exe > temp.bat` followed by `temp` and then `del temp.bat`.

Comment: it doesn't work accurately. if multiple copies of xyz.exe exists then it executes the file same time as number of time it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for /f %I in ('dir /s /b xyz.exe') do %I
```

Inside a batch file, you will need to use `%%I` instead of `%I`.

Comment: That only works if there are no spaces in the path to xyz.exe

Comment: @mbratch In which case, the following (more complex) line works: `for /f "tokens=1*" %i in ('dir /s /b xyz.exe') do "%i %j"`. With the same caveat that `%` needs to be changed to `%%` in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

This handles spaces and long filename elements.

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b "xyz.exe"') do "%%a"
```